# @Rohan Hapani - "please check my answer."

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

After short time after giving an answers he allways comment Q with this phrase ...

No problem with doing this after a longer period, but after this short time it *forces* Q to react.

Even if answers are right ...

- it smells like of misuage of comments
- it is unpolite
- already accepted answer disatracts others

Possible to give him a call?

---

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/51810/rohan-hapani?tab=answers

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257217/unknown-directory-type-while-generate-file-in-custom-folder-magento-2 I can see again :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for raising this.
The user has been notified.
if you see this behavior again, please report back.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257082/get-salesrule-id-from-order-id-in-magento-2 I can see again :)